# Calling function in C that receives pointer to function from Python

Tags: python, c, swig

I am using Swig to make a python library from C source code.
There is a function that receives a pointer to function in C. I need to call it from Python but the callback function must be in Python. 
All documentation I have seen uses callback functions in C.

Example:

```
typedef double (*FeeCalculator)(Transaction* p);

void dealTransaction(Transaction* t, FeeCalculator feeCalculator);
```

I want that function to be usable in Python. Something like:

```
def myFeeCalculator(tran):
    return trans.Sum * 0.1

def main():
   t = Transaction()
   dealTransaction(t, myFeeCalculator)
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: Thanks, I added an example.

Comment: even though most of the code is written in C are you able to write some C++ for the Python wrapper only? The glue can be simplified quite a bit with just a little bit of C++

Answer (score 0):

thanks Flexo.
This is what I did:

This is what I finally did:

Swig:

```
%{

typedef double (*FeeCalculator)(Transaction* p);
typedef struct{
    FeeCalculator callback;
    void* context;
} FeeCalculatorCallbackAndContext;

void dealTransaction(Transaction* t, FeeCalculatorCallbackAndContext* feeCalculator);

double __WrapperCallback(Transaction * t, void* context){
    PyObject *pTransaction = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(t), SWIGTYPE_p_Transaction, 0 );
    PyObject* feeCalc = (PyObject*)context;
    PyObject *result = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(feeCalc, pTransaction, NULL);
    double r = PyFloat_FromDouble(result);
    Py_DECREF(result);
    return r;
}

%typemap(in) FeeCalculatorCallbackAndContext* (FeeCalculatorCallbackAndContext temp) {
  if (!PyCallable_Check($input)) SWIG_fail;
  temp.callback = __WrapperCallback;
  temp.context = $input;
  $1 = &temp;
}

%}
```

C:

```
void dealTransaction(Transaction* t, FeeCalculatorCallbackAndContext* feeCalculator){
    feeCalculator->callback(t, feeCalculator->context);
}
```

Call from Python:

```
import myLib

def myFeeCalculator(tran):
    return trans.Sum * 0.1

def main():
   t = Transaction()
   myLib.dealTransaction(t, myFeeCalculator)
```